# Toolbar on right side of the screen in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, multi-touch

I am trying to make a WPF application in which there is a drag able toolbar on the screen through which user can select different type of tools and use it on canvas. Also can someone tell me how to make a transparent canvas. A good example would be from [this picture in which there is drag able toolbar on right side of the picture. And the user can also work on any window he wants.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYRaI.jpg) I am new to WPF and I am trying to find a solution to my problem for quite a while now. Can someone guide me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Background DP default value is null. When a Background is set to null the displayed Color is White and mouse interactions don't work. You need to set Canvas's, ListBox's and ListBoxItem's Background to Transparent to see the Background of the Parent Control

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a toolbar, think of that as a window.
I would take a look at avalondock.

A transparent canvas:

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent"
```

As an aside, this is a couple of steps on from wpf beginner level.

If you take a look at this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM6Oe.jpg

The user is designing a game scenario. They drag units out the panel on the left ( it's a treeview ) onto the canvas on the right. Only this is not just a plain canvas, it's an itemscontrol with a canvas as the itemspresenter.  That allows me to template out the units from a collection of unit view models. It's using the mvvm pattern.
If you've not come across this technique it's a bit strange.  Here's a couple of samples to take a look at which templates out different viewmodels into different UI objects. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385QhgooJ94uO6PopIDs4lQ
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385QhgooLcGrZOSwFswa-Dg
The datatype is used to decide what you get in the view for what viewmodel.

You have a bit of a complication in that you decided you want a dockable panel usable in multiple windows.  Maybe that's not a must have.

Drag drop in my app isn't actually drag drop and relies on an odd aspect of a canvas. They don't clip, so you can add something to a canvas but have it positioned off the canvas.
As you start dragging a unit, it's viewmodel is added to the collection bound to my units itemscontrol.  That templates it into the canvas as a piece.  I work out the location compared to the canvas, so it'll have a negative X aspect which I bind to Canvas.Left.
Each unit is inside a thumb.  A thumb is the rectangle you drag up and down on or side to side on a slider. They are designed for dragging.  This way dragging is smooth and I can easily have a unit under the cursor that's being dragged.